How is the translation of WSL path to Windows achieved when calling "code ." in a WSL2 instance?
I was looking into Zed as a potential replacement for VSC, one of the key points of annoyance I've found is that even when calling "zed.exe ." inside of a WSL instance: showing WSL directory in which zed.exe is called
I get defaulted to my windows users folder: showing directory in which Zed opened
How does VSC manage to keep the same directory between subsystem and main OS and can I either apply it in my own build of Zed or contribute it as an optional change to the project? It seems to treat the current repository/directory name as file name to create in "mnt/c/Users/MyName/" and not as a whole path in which to open zed.exe in
This seemingly also works fine with other programs like explorer.exe as shown here: image of explorer.exe being called inside WSL and correctly opening in the WSL directory
I tried setting up the code editor Zed in windows but also being able to call it inside WSL like you can do VSC with "code ." but instead with "zed.exe ." instead of opening up in the current directory it opens in my windows users folder with the intended directory's name as a name file it created

I'm able to get Zed to open up in the current directory in WSL by installing the Linux version of Zed in WSL (link), rather than using the Windows executable.
Here is the bash alias I used to open Zed:
alias zed="export ZED_ALLOW_EMULATED_GPU=1 && export DISPLAY=:0 && WAYLAND_DISPLAY='' ~/.local/zed.app/bin/zed . --foreground &"


does not work for me, in WSL2 ubuntu at least
